# Convert multiple pdfs to txt in a folder PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

I try the following code but it converts only the last pdf in the folder:

```
import fitz  # this is pymupdf
import glob, os
os.chdir('C:/Users/XXXXXXX')
pdfs = []
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
 with fitz.open(file) as doc:
    text = ""
    for page in doc:
        text += page.getText()
textfile = open('textfile.txt', 'w',encoding="utf-8")
textfile.write(text)
```

can you help me ?!?!?!?!

i am using python 3.8!

Comment: Well you initialize `text = ""` with each iteration...

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that your loop isn't working, (and it probably is), you can use `os.walk("start_dir")` instead. For example:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):  # All files.
    for file in files:  # Loop through each file.
        with fitz.open(file) as doc:  # Open file.
            ...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply!!! it goes through the folder and it converts pdfs merging the content  in one txt (textfile.txt). i need as many txt file as the pdfs (maintaining the same name possibly)

Comment: Yes, you would have to save the text after each document, so if you put your code to save the file in the `for` loop, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `getText` what to get. Then append that text to a list outside of the loop so it is not overwritten. Finally convert that list to a string.

Edit: I've modified my original answer to do what you asked. In order to write them to individual `.txt` files you to include the writing of the file into the loop. Don't forget to close `textfile` before moving to the next pdf or it will not write the following file.

```
import fitz
import glob, os

DIR = '\\pdftext\\'
os.chdir(DIR + 'pdf\\')

def listToString(s):  
    str1 = ""  
    for ele in s:  
        str1 += ele   
    return str1  

for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    print(file)
    filename = os.path.splitext(file)
    filename = filename[0]
    pdfs = []

    with fitz.open(file) as doc:
        text = ""
        for page in doc:
            text += page.getText(text)
            pdfs.append(text)
        
        textfile = open(DIR + 'text\\' + filename + '.txt', 'w',encoding="utf-8")
    pages = listToString(pdfs)
    textfile.write(pages)
    textfile.close()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply!!! it goes through the folder and it converts pdfs merging the content in one txt (textfile.txt). i need as many txt file as the pdfs (maintaining the same name possibly)

Answer (score 0):

i tried:

```
import sys, fitz
import glob
for fname in glob.glob("C:/Users/XXXXXX/*.pdf"):

doc = fitz.open(fname) # open document
out = open(fname + ".txt", "wb") # open text output
for page in doc: # iterate the document pages
    text = page.getText().encode("utf8") # get plain text (is in UTF-8)
    out.write(text) # write text of page
    out.write(bytes((12,))) # write page delimiter (form feed 0x0C)
 out.close()
```

it works but i still have to test the result :-)